# Creating a Help Center in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, center

I'm developing a program in vb.net, and I want to add in some help pages to the program, without using web-based help, so more like when you hit F1 in the Microsoft Office programs.

Is there a straightforward way of doing this, other than just making it via lots of forms?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: CHM is the keyword you're looking for.  http://helpware.net/mshelp2/demo2/h1xNET.htm

Comment: Brilliant, that looks just right!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a small Sqlite database with the help content and a help browser that reads the content from the database?

Other than that you have CHM and HLP formats. With CHM you can use the [HelpProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.helpprovider.aspx) to provide this information to your user.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help